# Mac OS X Code Signing and Executable Validation

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing, pki

I work on a vertical-market Mac application that uses a USB dongle to make sure users have paid for it. It's expensive enough, and in enough demand, that "black hats" have tried to crack the dongle scheme, so the app checks the executable and key resource files at runtime, and if something has been tampered with, the program won't run.

With PKI (Public Key Infrastructure) based code signing becoming more commonplace in the Mac world, I'm considering switching to using it to do this runtime verification, which would have the nice side effect of making Gatekeeper happy.

However, Apple's interest is very different from mine. Their focus is on making the user happy, so if an app has an incorrect signature, Mac OS X will simply ask the user if they want to run it anyway. My focus is on thwarting crackers, so if my app has an incorrect signature, I simply don't want it to do anything that's useful to an end-user.

So I want my app to be able to validate its own executable and resources, using Apple's signatures, at runtime.

Also, from what I've read of the libraries offered Mac OS X for doing validation, they simply give a "yes" or "no" answer to requests to validate an executable. It strikes me that this is susceptible to "black hat" attack in a number of ways - for instance, one could simply replace Apple's tools with ones that always say, "yes, this is valid", either in the system directories or by changing the search path for those tools. So I think it might be a good idea to build the complete set of signature validation code into my app.

So I have a few questions:

1. What PKI libraries/APIs are available to let an app validate its own executable and resources which have been signed using Apple's codesign system?
2. Do these libraries have source code available?
3. Are my security concerns about using the PKI libraries Apple ships with Mac OS X valid, or are they safer to use than I think?
4. Does anybody have experience with this kind of thing they'd be willing to share? Are there other gotchas or tips?

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: +1 You need to be "poacher, turned gamekeeper" in the copy-protection game.  It doesn't look like you were ever a black hat yourself.  It's an interesting question though.

Comment: @trojanfoe: True, I was never a black hat.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Speaking of which... are there things I'm missing here in terms of securing the code against modification, or other means of defeating the use of the USB dongle?

Comment: I just think it's impossible to stop a cracker modifying your code, but you can make it very hard.  However it's very hard to get that right.

Comment: I agree it's impossible, but I simply want to make it hard enough that it's not worth bothering with. For my purposes, it's adequate for the program to refuse to run if either the executable image or a key resource file on disk has been modified from the release version - hence, the program verifies them against their digital signatures. If a cracker has pulled something fancier, like code injection, that's a horse of a different color.

Comment: Well I'd be interested in your progress; I am releasing early next  year, via MAS, and intend to make it as hard as possible.  However neither of us is likely to share our progress given the nature of the work...

Comment: @trojanfoe: I don't mind sharing progress. A rule of thumb for modern cryptography is that good systems are hard to crack even if the details are known, since "security through obscurity" doesn't work well in the real world.

Comment: That is very true Bob, however (I think) that generally only works for public/private keypairs where you can divulge the algorithm and the public key and be safe in the knowledge that it doesn't endanger your crypto scheme. When you talk about software protection however you don't have this luxury as the "private key bit" has to be available in order to decrypt and therefore has to be hidden somehow.

Comment: @trojanfoe: I'm planning to use a scheme that fits your first sentence. (1) Use the private key to encrypt a SHA-256 hash of the executable to form a signature. (2) The signature and the public key will ship with the executable. (3) At runtime the executable will be re-compute its own hash, and compares that with the value that comes from decrypting the signature. The public key can be built into the executable itself, and the private key never needs to be divulged.

Comment: While I'm no expert with crypto, the usual method is to encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key.  When I looked into this a while back it's not the same the reverse the roles of the keys and expect it to be as secure: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148820/how-to-encrypt-data-using-the-private-key

Comment: When creating a digital signature, you encrypt with the private key and decrypt with the public key: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature#How_they_work

Comment: Nowadays _code injection_ of the running process can be averted by the _hardened runtime_ in macOS 10.14.6. Whereas guards against code modification is theoretically can be done by validating the app's signature, it probably be more fool-proof if you can delegate validation to the dongle itself. I.e. send encrypted hashes to the dongle and let it validate with its own list of hashes and embedded public key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer #1 and #2 above, Apple has open-sourced its code for creating and verifying digital signatures as libsecurity_codesigning. So a developer could build that into their app to let it validate its own signature.

Alternatively, MacOS's version of this library can be used by an app - but the API is private, so that's a gotcha. There's a [brief discussion at this link](http://codepimpsdotorg.blogspot.com/2009/03/using-code-signing-in-os-x.html).